# How to prevent the images in multi-carousel from overlapping each other?

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have implemented a bootstrap4 multi-carousel . But the images are overlapping each other as such as all the six items are occupying the screen edge to edge once at a time.

I have included HTML, CSS and JS files.

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="MultiCarousel" data-items="1,3,5,6" data-slide="1"            id="MultiCarousel"  data-interval="1000">
        <div class="MultiCarousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="pad15 pad">
                    <img src="files/products_02.jpg" alt="ball">
                    <p class="lead">Loreum Ipsum Loreum</p>
                    <p>₹ 6000</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="pad15">
                        <img src="files/products_03.gif" alt="ball">
                        <p class="lead">Loreum Ipsum Loreum</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="pad15">
                        <img src="files/products_04.gif" alt="ball">
                        <p class="lead">Loreum Ipsum Loreum</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="pad15">
                        <img src="files/products_05.gif" alt="ball">
                        <p class="lead">Loreum Ipsum Loreum</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="pad15">
                        <img src="bat4.jpeg" alt="ball">
                        <p class="lead">Loreum Ipsum Loreum</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="pad15">
                        <img src="ball1.jpeg" alt="ball">
                        <p class="lead">Loreum Ipsum Loreum</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary leftLst"><</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary rightLst">></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
        .MultiCarousel { float: left; overflow: hidden; padding: 15px;   width: 100%; position:relative; }
        .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner { transition: 1s ease all; float: left; }
        .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item { float: left;}
        .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item > div { text-align: center; padding:10px; margin:10px; background:#f1f1f1; color:#666;}
        .MultiCarousel .leftLst, .MultiCarousel .rightLst { position:absolute; border-radius:50%;top:calc(50% - 20px); }
        .MultiCarousel .leftLst { left:0; }
        .MultiCarousel .rightLst { right:0; }

        .MultiCarousel .leftLst.over, .MultiCarousel .rightLst.over { pointer-events: none; background:#ccc; }
```

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var itemsMainDiv = ('.MultiCarousel');
        var itemsDiv = ('.MultiCarousel-inner');
        var itemWidth = "";

        $('.leftLst, .rightLst').click(function () {
            var condition = $(this).hasClass("leftLst");
            if (condition)
                click(0, this);
            else
                click(1, this)
        });

        ResCarouselSize();

        $(window).resize(function () {
            ResCarouselSize();
        });

        //this function define the size of the items
        function ResCarouselSize() {
            var incno = 0;
            var dataItems = ("data-items");
            var itemClass = ('.item');
            var id = 0;
            var btnParentSb = '';
            var itemsSplit = '';
            var sampwidth = $(itemsMainDiv).width();
            var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
            $(itemsDiv).each(function () {
                id = id + 1;
                var itemNumbers = $(this).find(itemClass).length;
                btnParentSb = $(this).parent().attr(dataItems);
                itemsSplit = btnParentSb.split(',');
                $(this).parent().attr("id", "MultiCarousel" + id);


                if (bodyWidth >= 1200) {
                    incno = itemsSplit[3];
                    itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
                }
                else if (bodyWidth >= 992) {
                    incno = itemsSplit[2];
                    itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
                }
                else if (bodyWidth >= 768) {
                    incno = itemsSplit[1];
                    itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
                }
                else {
                    incno = itemsSplit[0];
                    itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
                }
                $(this).css({ 'transform': 'translateX(0px)', 'width': itemWidth * itemNumbers });
                $(this).find(itemClass).each(function () {
                    $(this).outerWidth(itemWidth);
                });

                $(".leftLst").addClass("over");
                $(".rightLst").removeClass("over");

            });
        }


        //this function used to move the items
        function ResCarousel(e, el, s) {
            var leftBtn = ('.leftLst');
            var rightBtn = ('.rightLst');
            var translateXval = '';
            var divStyle = $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform');
            var values = divStyle.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
            var xds = Math.abs(values[4]);
            if (e == 0) {
                translateXval = parseInt(xds) - parseInt(itemWidth * s);
                $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).removeClass("over");

                if (translateXval <= itemWidth / 2) {
                    translateXval = 0;
                    $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).addClass("over");
                }
            }
            else if (e == 1) {
                var itemsCondition = $(el).find(itemsDiv).width() - $(el).width();
                translateXval = parseInt(xds) + parseInt(itemWidth * s);
                $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).removeClass("over");

                if (translateXval >= itemsCondition - itemWidth / 2) {
                    translateXval = itemsCondition;
                    $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).addClass("over");
                }
            }
            $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform', 'translateX(' + -translateXval + 'px)');
        }

        //It is used to get some elements from btn
        function click(ell, ee) {
            var Parent = "#" + $(ee).parent().attr("id");
            var slide = $(Parent).attr("data-slide");
            ResCarousel(ell, Parent, slide);
        }

    });
```

I expect the output such that all the images occupy their original dimensions or at least are responsive. Also i want only four images to be displayed at once , and the rest of the images to show up only on pressing the right and left arrow buttons. Right now all the six images are displayed at once.

Comment: Try adding .MultiCarousel .item img { max-width:100%; } or adding the class '.img-fluid' to the <img />

Comment: @Miguel M. Indeed, after applying .MultiCarousel .item img { max-width:100%; } , the images are not overlapping anymore. But i want only four images to be displayed at once , and the rest of the images to show up only on pressing the right and left arrow buttons. Right now all the six images are displayed at once. How to achieve that?

Comment: You can add the class '.col-md-3' to the '.item' div that will make each item take 25% of the screen width. You can play around with different widths for different screen sizes by reading this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

apply following css in your code. Hope this is useful.

```
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item > div{overflow:hidden}
img { max-width:100%; }
```

Comment: The answer is very close to the solution except that its adding some extra spacing (padding or margin) at the right. In this case , @Miguel M's answer is just fine.

Comment: did you get the answer or still you need fix ?

Comment: I got my answer except that i want to display 4 images at once at a time instead of 6. Adding class '.col-md-3' as suggested by Miguel M. does not seem to work though.